# PySpark: Count every element in flatmap

Tags: pyspark

I am having trouble counting every element in a list that I have created in PySpark.

Here is what I am working with:

test2 = words.filter(lambda line: re.match(r'^[AEIOU]', line)).take(10)

> > > test2
> > >       [u'EBook', u'Author:', u'English', u'OF', u'EBOOK', u'Inc.,', u'Etext', u'Inc.,', u'Etexts', u'Etext']

Now I want to confirm the count of test2 is 10. But everytime I use test2.count(), it's giving me an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

Can someone help me learn how to count the elements properly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**test2** is a list, so you should be doing `len(test2)` to find the number of elements. The function **count()**, when called on a list, will return the number of occurrences of whatever you pass as a parameter.